# Linux Mint Rebecca - Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management, repository

Whenever I do

> sudo apt-get update

I get the following error

> W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/rebecca/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch
>   http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/rebecca/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages
>   404 Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did it used to work? mongodb.org currently only has Ubuntu packages for trusty and precise. As http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ says, "MongoDB only provides packages for long-term support Ubuntu releases. Currently, this means 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) and 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)."

Answer (score 2):

Most possible, it means that the repository does not exist anymore.

I have Russian version of Linux Mint, so, excuse me, maybe I will write not exact names below. But I try to translate.

You can go to Update Manager (rus. "Менеджер обновлений"). Just click on pictogram with "**i**" on bottom panel.

Then choose menu "Edit" -- "Sources of applications" (rus. "Источники приложений") and find here your wrong repository.
(http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/rebecca/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages)
You can off it here and error message will disappear.